# Occasionally encounter error “ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer”

Tags: linux, ssh

I have posted this question on Serverfault (https://serverfault.com/questions/701920/occasionally-encounter-error-ssh-exchange-identification-read-connection-rese), but get no answers. Hence I repost this question here, hoping to get more exposure to experts.

When I try to connect a remote Linux server using ssh, sometimes I got the error `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer` while other times I can connect to the server successfully. This error also occurs while I have another successful ssh connection already open and can run command on the server.

On the server side (a Ubuntu machine), I found no record of the failed connection in either */var/log/syslog*, or *auth.log*.

On my local machine, `ssh IP -vv` gives the following information which does not seem help either,

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to IP [IP] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/luke/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luke/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug1: identity file /home/luke/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luke/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luke/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luke/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luke/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luke/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Any idea how to debug this error? It actually happens rather frequently, but the difficult part is that it does not always happen. I also tried to install exact same version of openSSH and install same Ubuntu version in VirtualBox and connect from there, none of these helps.

Comment: Sounds a bit like a flakey network. Maybe some surprising routing effect or similar. Package drops.

Comment: @arkascha Thanks for answering. Any way to confirm the reason? I can work normally using the other opened connection but see this error when try to open a new connection.

Comment: You could try a debugging proxy like Charles for this. It allows to sniff encrypted connections, but that is a lot of work. Not sure if it pays off. Also, if you have not yet tried, raise the debugging level as a first step to get more details.

Comment: @arkascha I tried raise the debugging level, did not help. I will try Charles if this error happens more often. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Take a look at https://superuser.com/a/857206/54530 or https://superuser.com/a/744678/54530 (it's the same problem; the error is just phrased differently).

Comment: @Kenster Thanks for answering. The difference between my problem and others is the error I have occurs sometimes, but not always. And as I said, I cannot find any record on the server side about the failed attempts.